# Elasticsearch not saving emoji

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

How we can enable saving of emoji or emoticons in elasticsearch.

As emoji is not supported it becomes ????? instead of emoji. I am able to save the unicode characters and data from different languages but not emoji.

Eg: Emoticons 
becomes Emoticons ????

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'id'    => 'my_id',
    'body'  => [ 'testField' => 'Test emoji ']
];

// Document will be indexed to my_index/_doc/my_id
$response = $client->index($params);
```

Comment: There's nothing special to do in order to save emojis, it works out of the box. Try it from the Dev Tools console in Kibana and you'll see. It might have to do with the encoding used by your PHP client, maybe.

Comment: yes it was dumb issue, i was using wrong encoding in database connection. Thanks